# Managing opening and closing of reusable Modal in React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a reusable Modal using React+Redux but I am not able to manage opening and closing of the same correctly.

The modal needs to open on click of a link on parent component and needs to close on click of a button inside the Modal.

**Question-1** 
I tried using React Refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html and it all worked fine but the approach seems not the correct one as per the documentation of Refs(or could be that am understanding it wrong). Can someone throw light on this?

**Question-2** 
I have been trying using props and state to trigger the opening and closing of Model. Whats the best way to manage this? Is it by adding a toggle function in parent and using it so that on each click in parent the child is updated and rendered again? How to handle the close in this case?

Comment: Look into React Portals: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set a modal property in the parent state to control the display of the modal, and pass it a close function as props which sets that state to false from the modal when you want to toggle it.

```
toggleModal() {
  this.setState({
    modal: !this.state.modal
})
}

<Modal show={this.state.modal} close={this.state.toggleModal} />
```

The relevant parts of the modal:

```
  onClose(e) {
      this.props.close && this.props.close(e);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div
        className="custom-modal"
        id="modal"
      >
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-close" onClick={this.onClose}>
            X
          </div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```